# VB.Net, Filter DataGridView by range input by user

Tags: mysql, vb.net, forms, datagridview, filter

I am really stuck on an idea I have but need some examples, I hope somebody can help, I would really appreciate it.

I have a DataGridView that pulls down data from a MySQL Database, the data consists of hundreds of rows and each row has a location cell i.e.. (01A, 02A, 03A) all the way up to 99Z, what I want is for the user to input a location range and the datagridview to filter out everything else.

Example using two text boxes and a button.
User inputs '05C' in to textbox1 and '10E' in to textbox2 and clicks ok.
The datagridview will filter out everything except rows that contain all locations between and including '05C' and '10E'.

All locations go from A to Z and each letter from 1 to 99.

I hope I have described this well enough, and I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a few examples, I have googled and searched but cannot find any examples of what I am looking for.

Many Thanks.
Please feel free to private message me if you wish.

Comment: Sounds like you want a DataView

Comment: If I used a DataView, would the following work?
DataView.RowFilter = "Location >= 05C and Location <= 10E"

Comment: Can you alter the table.
You could separate the alpha and numeric values into 2 columns [ColAlph] and [ColNum]. Then you could select rows 
where [colalph] >= rangestartAlph and [colalph] <= rangeEndAlph And [ColNum] >= rangestartNum and  [ColNum] <= rangeEndNum

Forgive the syntax if you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I'm not able to alter the locations table.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** changed answer to fit OP requirements

You can filter your datasource to get the results you need.
On your filter button event do this

```
 Dim bs As New BindingSource
        bs.DataSource = 'Here goes the datasource of your gridview'
        bs.Filter = gridCreation.Columns(i).HeaderText.ToString() + ">=" + TextBox1.Text + " and " + gridCreation.Columns(i).HeaderText.ToString() + "<=" + TextBox2.Text
        //i would be the column number where your location row is.
        //Remember that the index starts on 0

        DataGridView.DataSource = bs
        DataGridView.DataBind()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but it's a WinForms application not web.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to re-select all the data then store it again to your datagridview

```
SELECT <whatever> FROM <yourtable> WHERE ID >= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and ID <= '" & TextBox2.Text & "'" 'I thought that it was the ID column lol idk, change it to whatever it must be.
```

Then store the query as `your_datagridview.DataSource` then your datagridview will re-load all the data.

Put that in the `your_button` on Click Event.

Hope this helps.